# How to decrypt FormsAuthenticationTicket in mvc c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, form-authentication

I am encrypt the password and store it to session value using **FormsAuthenticationTicket**, when I retrieve it I can not able to decrypt the password.

**Encrypt like below**

```
    string pw="xyz";
    FormsAuthenticationTicket ticketpw = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(pw, true, 1000);
    string securepw = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticketpw);

    Session["password"] = securepw;
```

**I tried to Decrypt Like below**
**Try 1**

```
            FormsAuthenticationTicket ticketuname = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(pw, true, 1000);
            string secureuname = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(pw);

            Session["password"] = securepw;
```

**Try 2**

```
            string securepw=FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(pw);               
            Session["password"] = securepw;
```

**Error -** Can not convert FormAuthenticationTicket to String

Comment: What's the point of encrypting a value if you store it in session, at the server side? You could as well store it in plain text, the session container is not available to users directly. Another question, though, is, why do you need to store user password at the server side?

Comment: @WiktorZychla I am using converse.js for chating purpose, when the user register or login to my home page, I need to send the username and password to clientside (for converse.js)

Comment: Sounds like a potential security hole, you should avoid storing user passwords in plain text, not to mention sending passwords anywhere in plain text. I strongly suggest you rethink your approach. Possibly, if a user is already logged in to your website and your website issued an encrypted cookie, you don't really need the password anymore. Hard to be sure, however, without more details on your architecture.

Comment: @WiktorZychla I will use this encrypted password only for chatting purpose, have any chance to hack or other problem? When the user login I will encrypt this password and send to client side for chat login. Please suggest more because I am new to login registration process too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because you create new ticket differently than ticket it got encrypted. Best practice is to put it in an `HttpCookie` and then retrieve it:

```
  FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,
    username,
    DateTime.Now,
    DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),
    isPersistent,
    userData,
    FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);

  // Encrypt the ticket.
  string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);

  // Create the cookie.
  Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket));
```

And decrypt:

```
var authCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];

if (authCookie == null) return;
var cookieValue = authCookie.Value;

if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cookieValue)) return;
var ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookieValue)
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.encrypt(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Should I need to store these information to cookies?

Comment: @MerbinJo there are multiple override for constructor, see suitable for your case.

Comment: thanks for your answer **my problem is solved**, but WiktorZychla he said about some security issue.

Comment: @MerbinJo if this solve your problem, mark it as answer so other can use it.